# How to Get rawContent in nutch 1.14 while indexing

Tags: html, nutch

I am trying to write my own index-html plugin for Apache nutch 1.14. how do i get "rawContent" of html in nutch 1.14 with version 2.3.1 we are able to get it through WebPage  but with 1.14 version we get only text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Nutch 1.14 you should already have the option `-addBinaryContent` on the index command/job (see https://github.com/apache/nutch/blob/release-1.14/src/java/org/apache/nutch/indexer/IndexingJob.java#L171). This means that with this flag you could send the raw bytes to your indexing backend. Also you could encode it as base64 with the corresponding flag (useful if your indexing backend doesn't have a bytes type).

Comment: Thanks a lot Jorge !! -addBinaryContent solved the problem and i am able to get binaryContent in back-end which i can use while indexing.